# Where is Analytics option in Android Studio 2.2 previews?

Tags: android, google-analytics

There was a Analytic option in Android Studio 2.0 version as shown below screenshot,

Flie Menu -> Project Structure

> [image]

But it is not present in Android Studio 2.2 version.

> [image]

Can anyone help me to find Analytic option in Android Studio 2.2 ?

Comment: This maybe related to the announcement of Firebase Analytics that is replacing Google Analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Google Analytics is being replaced by Firebase Analytics, you want to look at the new [Firebase plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/firebase-plugin) for Android Studio.
Here the video presenting it: https://youtu.be/csaXml4xtN8?t=1769